# Definition of multihomomorphis, and how to recognise their diagonal restriction

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

I am working on non commutative homogeneus Lie groups and I was wandering if there is a generalisation of the concept of multilinear map (tensors, as we know are defined on the tangent). I define multiomomorphism as a map:

$\phi:G^k=G\times G\times\ldots\times G\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R},+)$

for which $\phi$ is a homomorphism in each component and it is $k$ homogeneus wrt dilations of the group. Are these objects studied? How are they called in literature? I can find almost nothing on the web.

In particular I would like to understand if it is possible to characterise $k$ homogeneus maps $\psi:G\to\mathbb{R}$ which are possible to write as:

$\psi(a)=\phi(a,a,\ldots,a)$.

I particuarly appreciate indications for references.

Comment: "Dilatation" does not mean anything in a Lie group.

Comment: homogeneus means with a automoprhism group which differential is the dilation (possibly anisotropic) on the tangent.

Comment: Usually, there are none of those.

Comment: the Heisenberg group is such I am afraid, Homogeneus simply connected, connected lie groups are nilpotent and endoewd with suitable metrics are known as Carnot groups. Moreover you can build multihom multipling homomorphisms. Thus i don't understand your comment